# How to (click) on angular material selected tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular11, mat-tab

I want to  change page when I click on  selectedTab,  url is same on all tab.

```
  <mat-tab-group class="d-block" animationDuration="0ms" [selectedIndex]="tabSelectedIndex"
  (selectedIndexChange)="tabSelectedIndex = $event" class="licenses">

  <mat-tab [label]="'a' | translate" #a (click)="changeExtensionOfTerm()"></mat-tab>

  <mat-tab [label]="'b' | translate" #b></mat-tab>

  <mat-tab [label]="'c' | translate" #c></mat-tab>

  <mat-tab [label]="'d' | translate" #d></mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

WHen  selected is first tab there is  two step which is controled by  behaviorSubject

```
 something=  new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

when I click again on selected tab I want to

```
something.next(false);
```

but   mat-tab  has no output  for (click), also I tried  selectedTabChange, but if tab has already selected,  this method doesn't call again.

Comment: Did you still looking for this ?

Comment: NO, I have already written.

Comment: there is function which  gets tabindex as parameter and   check if  index is 0    this.something.next(true);

Comment: Great, So now you have working solution fine.